# Displaying CLOB Column with 4000+ characters

Tags: oracle, clob

I have this CLOB column and I need to display it using a select statement.

I used `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` to convert it to `varchar2`:

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(T1.CLOB_COL,4000,1) CLOB_COL from T1
```

My problem is some of my CLOBS contains more than 4000 characters. How can I display it...any idea/suggestion?

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 11):

I guess you could display the chunks as separate rows ?

```
SELECT ROWNUM as chunk_no,ID, SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, (ROWNUM-1)*4000, 4000) AS chunk
FROM t1
CONNECT BY (ROWNUM-1)*4000 <= LENGTH(t1.clob_col)
```

or if there is a constraint on the maximum size a clob could be in your system you could hard code the number of text columns returned

```
SELECT SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, 1, 4000) AS pt1,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH (t1.clob_col) > 4000  THEN SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, 4001, 4000) END AS pt2,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH (t1.clob_col) > 8000  THEN SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, 8001, 4000) END AS pt3,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH (t1.clob_col) > 12000 THEN SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, 1201, 4000) END AS pt4
FROM t1
```

Comment: After searching and trying many different techniques, this is the only thing that worked for me, using straight SQL.  Most other solutions require PL/SQL or other methods that require special permissions.

Comment: You should add +1 at substr and change <=  to < in connect by to perfect it: SELECT ROWNUM as chunk_no,ID, SUBSTR (t1.clob_col, (ROWNUM-1)*4000 +1, 4000) AS chunk FROM t1 CONNECT BY (ROWNUM-1)*4000 < LENGTH(t1.clob_col)  otherwise you will get a character duplication @pos:4000